# How can I pull an existing heroku app to new location for development?

Tags: heroku, pull, git-pull

I currently have the latest version of my code on another computer that I want to develop from (Home computer and laptop for when I'm out and about) I set up heroku for my app on my laptop. Now I need to associate my code on my desktop so that I can push to heroku from there as well.

This is what I get from my desktop:

```
desktop:~/NetBeansProjects/onlinescheduler$ git pull heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can't do `heroku create` because that will create a separate app. How do I associated the existing code with (or pull down a brand new version from) heroku?

Whats the command to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to follow the Quick Start instructions for Heroku, which you can get straight from the horse's mouth, right here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

Once you've gotten through step 3, come back here.

Then, you can type this into the command line:
`heroku git:clone -a myapp`

This is described here: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app

Then, if you want to grab the database too, here are some options.
Newer Heroku instructions on import/export: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Older heroku instructions on push and pull: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

If you are using mongo, this is a useful tool to sync your mongo database: https://github.com/pedro/heroku-mongo-sync#readme

Comment: On import/export
Note also the heroku pgbackups:transfer command is very usefull
`$ heroku pgbackups:transfer --help `
`Usage: heroku pgbackups:transfer [SOURCE DATABASE] DESTINATION DATABASE`
`$ heroku pgbackups:transfer green teal --app example`

Comment: @JonathonBatson Hi there can we clone others existing apps?

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab you can find app cloning instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app

The command is `heroku git:clone -a myapp`

Comment: @ogoldberg hi thanks for your response i already know how to do it, but this means anyone can clone your app? how do  we make it private?

Answer (score 113):

Also, If you've never used heroku before on the other machine, you'll need to do a few more things first:

```
$ gem install heroku
```

```
$ heroku login
 [then enter your credentials]
```

```
$ heroku keys:add [path to keyfile]
```

Now you can clone the remote repository:

```
$ git clone git@heroku.com:<heroku_app>.git <local_directory>
```

Comment: this gives me an  "!   Internal server error" when adding the local key (a different one from that on my other machine). Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is the more correct way to do this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clone-heroku-app

Comment: Very helpful. Note that the keys command is by default not needed: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: Heroku CLI not needed. I added my public key in heroku user setting using web browser and then cloned it using: git clone git@heroku.com:<heroku_app>.git

Answer (score 5):

If you first need to get the app from Heroku, clone your app.

To do that, write in your Terminal:

```
heroku git:clone -a your_app_name
```

If you already have the app and the remote to heroku follow the next steps. If not, you can check instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

1. Find the name of your database

Write in your Terminal:

```
heroku pg:info -a your_app_name
```

it will look something like this:

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL
```

2. Find the name of your local database

In your Rails app go to **config/database.yml**

it will look something like this:

```
your_app_name_development
```

3. Clone your production database (PostgreSQL)

Write in your Terminal with your own database names:

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL your_app_name_development -a your_app_name
```

**HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL** is an example of how could be the name of your production database (in Heroku):
**my_app_name_development** is the name of your development database (locally)
**the_name_of_my_app** is the name of your app in **Heroku**

Don't forget to finish this with bundle install...

Comment: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL` wont work for most people as their url bash variable could be different. Suggest editing your post so that the command is more generic.

Comment: Yes, it says "it will look something like this"
But, Thanks anyways for your suggestion!
I updated it to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have your code base ready and have heroku setup, use:

```
$ heroku git:remote -a your_heroku_app
```

This will allow you to deploy from your new location.
Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a key in a new computer, you have to upload your new SSH key by typing `heroku keys:add`.