# How do I download source code for my application from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pull an existing heroku app to new location for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786062/how-can-i-pull-an-existing-heroku-app-to-new-location-for-development)

How do I download source code for my application from Heroku?

My developer left without telling me how to do it. So please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to clone your code from Heroku. Check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786062/how-can-i-pull-an-existing-heroku-app-to-new-location-for-development) for details.