# Bastard Heroku apps: who's the father? (That is, where's the originating local directory?)

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

Over the years I've created (and abandoned) a few apps on Heroku which were automatically assigned generic-yet-poetic names by Heroku as they were pushed up to Heroku's servers. Now when I log in to my Heroku account, there those poor little orphaned apps sit.

After all this time, I'm ready for a happy reconciliation.

The thing is, I can't remember which app project (directory on my local computer) they belong to. Is there some CLI command I can run inside a rails app directory . . . or some file I can examine . . . that will reveal which Heroku app they've fathered?

Is there some way I can use my Heroku account to name an app's daddy?

Where oh where is Maury Povich when you really need him?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how you could find the home directory remotely. But if you still remember where your ssh key is you can re-download your heroku app and start over with a new directory... Even if you do remember atleast finding the key is not too difficult. Then you can run these commands from your terminal to re-download your entire app.

```
$ gem install heroku
$ heroku login
 [then enter your credentials] 
$ heroku keys:add [path to keyfile]
$ git clone git@heroku.com:<heroku_app>.git <local_directory>
```

[Information about a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786062/how-can-i-pull-an-existing-heroku-app-to-new-location-for-development).

EDIT: Since Heroku updates with a git remote I think this also may help... Full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app).
Try this:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git
heroku git:remote -a project
```