# Error $ git pull --rebase Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, heroku

I am getting the following error when trying to pull code from heroku git

```
$ git pull --rebase
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked git status and got this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Any idea what is going on? I already cloned the code but I can't pull the latests updates. I am set as a collaborator on the app still so not sure why this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786062/how-can-i-pull-an-existing-heroku-app-to-new-location-for-development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message suggests, this has nothing to do with your working directory.

Either you do not have the rights, you are using a wrong private key, or the public key registered on your behalf is erroneous/outdated.